# Javascript Fetch Web API Works with MVC Attribute Routing From Index View but Not Other View

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, routes, fetch-api

I am using javascript fetch from two different views to update my database without leaving the page. I have decorated the method with [Route("api/SaveNewBool")]. Routing works correctly when I call it from Index.cshtml but not from Found.cshtml. Both views are in the Views/Home folder.

I call saveNewBool from the on change event of a checkbox in Index.cshtml as below, and everything works:

```
@using System.Text.Json;
@model ClientsPlusVisitTypesPlusDocs

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Client List";
    int i = 0;
    int IDint = 0;
    string IDstring = "";
    string entryWidth = "";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">SSRounds - Client List</h1>
</div>
<h6 class="subHeading">Client Tracking Services</h6>
<br />



<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            //omitted <th>s
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Clients[0].UA)  //this is boolean in the model
            </th>
            //more omitted <th>s
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Clients.Count; j++)
            {
                IDint = Model.Clients[j].ID;
                IDstring = IDint.ToString();
            <tr class="table-row">
                //omitted <td>s
<td>
                    @Html.CheckBox("UA", Model.Clients[j].UA, new { id = "UACheckBox-" + IDstring, onchange = "saveNewBool(" + IDstring + ", id, 'ClientIDSourceID', 'OnCall')" }) //this is boolean in the model
                </td>
                //more omitted <td>s
            </tr>
             }
    </tbody>
</table>

//omitted modal forms
```

But if I call it from a script in Found.cshtml it appears to route it to /Home/api/saveNewBool instead of /api/saveNewBool. I get a 404 error in the Chrome debugger:

> POST https://localhost:7058/Home/api/saveNewBool net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).

As expected if I browse to https://localhost:7058/Home/api/saveNewBool I get a 404 browser error, and if I browse to https://localhost:7058/api/saveNewBool the page comes up, although there is a "Page not working" error since there is no GET method. I have not yet mastered Postman to test it properly, but as I said it works fine when called from Index.cshtml.

Here is Found.cshtml where a button calls the javascript function "activate" which in turn calls saveNewBool:

```
@model List<DataLibrary.Models.FindModel>

@{int? testID = 0;}

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h2>Matching Clients:</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    //omitted <th>s
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model[0].Active). //boolean in the model
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
             {
                if (Model[i].ID != testID)   //skip duplicates generated from the Join
                {
                    testID = Model[i].PatientID;
                    <tr class="table-row-@i.ToString()">
                        //omitted <td>s
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model[i].Active) //boolean in the model
                        </td>
                        @{ if (!Model[i].Active)
                           {
                               <td>
                                   <input type="button" id="button-@i.ToString()" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="activate(@Model[i].PatientID, @i, this.value, this.id)" value="Activate" />
                               </td>
                           }
                        }
                    </tr>
                }

             }
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Find" asp-controller="Home"/>
        <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function activate(ID, index, action, btnID) {
        const activeCBs = document.getElementsByClassName("check-box");
        activeCBs[index].setAttribute("id", "currentCB");   //Html DisplayFor helper won't set an id so set it here in order to pass the id to saveNewBool
        if (action == "Activate") {
            activeCBs[index].checked = true;
            document.getElementById(btnID).value = "Undo";
            saveNewBool(ID, "currentCB", "Demo", "Active");
        }
        if (action == "Undo") {
            activeCBs[index].checked = false;
            document.getElementById(btnID).value = "Activate";
            saveNewBool(ID, "currentCB", "Demo", "Active");
        }
        
    }
</script>

<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>  //site.js is where the saveNewBool function is located
```

Here is the saveNewBool function:

```
function saveNewBool(iD, elementID, tableName, dbColumn) {
    const newValue = document.getElementById(elementID).checked;
    const newInfo = {
        "ID": iD, "NewInfo": newValue, "Table": tableName, "Column": dbColumn
    };    //make sure the object keys match the object at the api endpoint

    fetch('api/SaveNewBool', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newInfo)
    })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
}
```

From DemoController:

```
[HttpPost()]
        [Route("api/SaveNewBool")]
        public void SaveNewBool([FromBody] Models.DataBoolChangeModel newBoolData)
        {
            SqlDataAccess.SaveNewBool(newBoolData.ID, newBoolData.NewInfo, newBoolData.Table, newBoolData.Column);
        }
```

I am using HttpPost to lower the chance of reverse engineering some of the IDs. I put the HttpPost method in a "DemoController" instead of the "HomeController" mostly to make sure I understood routing, which I clearly don't. I decorated the HttpPost method with attribute routing for the same reason.

Here is Program.cs where conventional routing is set up:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SSRounds.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; //prevents cross-site scripting exploits
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

I am from a generation that used paper and find it hard to overcome the concept of wasting it, so I have not included Models. I will include them if it would be helpful, and look forward to learning why.

I can't seem to find much on misrouted javascript fetch calls. Grasping at straws I included credentials [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587560/js-fetch-api-not-working-with-asp-net-core-2-controllers-with-authorize-attribut](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but that didn't help. I did have some capitalization differences in "saveNewBool" but correcting them doesn't seem to matter. I have also tried changing "fetch('api/SaveNewBool'..." to "fetch('/api/SaveNewBool'..." and "~/fetch('api/SaveNewBool'..." but still end up with routing to /Home/api/saveNewBool instead of /api/saveNewBool. If I specify the whole URL "fetch('https://localhost:7058/api/SaveNewBool', {..." then it works fine.

I suppose I could drop the same saveNewBool method into the HomeController but I'd rather figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like your `fetch()` uses a relative URL, meaning that it will be interpreted relative to the URL of the page that loaded the script.

Comment: Good point. I have edited the original post to include my trial of prefixing "api/SaveNewBool" with either "/" or "~/", neither of which changed the resulting route.

Comment: Thanks to @Pointy I have it working now. "fetch('../api/SaveNewBool', {..." works both when calling from Index.cshtml and Found.cshtml. I'm not going to answer my own question at this point because I still don't understand why the current working directory seems to be different when I call it from an onchange event in Index.cshtml vs. a button click calling a function in Found.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the API from Index.cshtml, the URL used is "/api/saveNewBool", but when you call it from Found.cshtml, the URL used is "/Home/api/saveNewBool". This is because the URL used is relative to the current page's URL, and since Found.cshtml is located in the "Home" folder, the URL becomes "/Home/api/saveNewBool".

To fix this issue, you can use the absolute URL for the API endpoint by prefixing it with a forward slash ("/api/saveNewBool") instead of relying on the relative URL. This will ensure that the API is always called from the root URL of the application, regardless of the current page's URL.

You can modify the fetch call in the saveNewBool function as follows:

```
fetch('/api/saveNewBool', {
  // options etc yolo
})
```

By using the absolute URL, you should be able to call the API successfully from both Index.cshtml and Found.cshtml.